# How to shim ObjectSet (EntityFramework)?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, c#-4.0, microsoft-fakes

I've shimmed my data context.  Now I need to shim a table get().  I'm running into issues with ObjectSet, since I don't know how to shim it.

```
DataModel.Fakes.ShimMyEntities.Constructor = (inst) => {};
DataModel.Fakes.ShimMyEntities.AllInstances.Table1Get = (i)
  => ?
```

//In codebase

```
using(MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
{
  ctx.Table1.ToList().ForEach(i => otherList.Add(i));
}
```

What should go where the question mark above is?  I've tried variations of the following in place of the question mark but nothing so far works:

```
=> { return new ObjectSet<Table1>(){ new ObjectContext("").CreateObjectSet<Table1>();} ; }
```

and

```
=> { return System.Data.Objects.Fakes.ShimObjectContext.AllInstances.CreateObjectSetOf1String<Table1>(inst, var1)   ???
```

Comment: I haven't used MS Fakes, but I have used Moq and DbSet/DbContext as outlined at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx.  Maybe that article will help you.

Comment: This issue is specific to MS Fakes.

Answer (score 2):

The following is how I do it:

```
var shimTable1ObjectSet = new System.Data.Objects.Fakes.ShimObjectSet<Table1>();
shimTable1ObjectSet.Bind((new List<Table1>()).AsQueryable());
DataModel.Fakes.ShimMyEntities.Constructor = (inst) => {};
DataModel.Fakes.ShimMyEntities.AllInstances.Table1Get = () => shimTable1ObjectSet.Instance;
```

With that you will be able to do `ToList()`, `Count()`, `Where()`, etc on that `ctx.Table1`.